# Trigger handler - query separate object based and update record

Tags: apex, map, before-trigger

I have a before insert trigger I'm struggling to design properly in a bulk manner. Here is what I would do in a non-bulk fashion - my challenge is that I'm not using the ID of the trigger object in my other query but two other conditions from the trigger object. I wouldn't implement anything like this but hopefully the below pseudo code explains what I'm trying to do. I suspect I need to load it into a map first but without going from an ID on Account I'm a little unclear on how to do this. Thank you!

Method called from before insert trigger:

```
public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Account> newAccountList ){  

    for(Account objAcct : newAccountList ){

        if(newAccountList.System_Generated__c  == true){
          //query a custom object for match
          for (Region__c region : [SELECT custom_field_1__c, custom_field_2__c FROM Region__c WHERE custom_field_3__c = :newAccountList.custom_field__3 AND custom_field_4__c = :newAccountList.custom_Field_4__c){
              newAccountList.custom_field_1__c = region.custom_field_1__c;
              newAccountList.custom_field_2__c = region.custom_field_2__c;
              update newAccountList;

       }
     }
   }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you need to update two fields on each Account from a corresponding Region, and the corresponding Region is determined by a combination of two other fields on that Account. Right? I'm also assuming that these fields are strings below.

You can achieve this using a more or less standard query/map pattern, there's just a bit more of a wrinkle because of the two fields.

First, you'd iterate over your Accounts and collect their values for `custom_field_3__c` and `custom_field_4__c`.

```
Set<String> customField3s = new Set<String>();
Set<String> customField4s = new Set<String>();

for (Account a : newAccountList) {
    customField3s.add(a.custom_field_3__c);
    customField4s.add(a.custom_field_4__c);
}
```

Then query all of your Regions:

```
List<Region__c> regions = [SELECT custom_field_1__c, custom_field_2__c FROM Region__c WHERE custom_field_3__c IN :customField3s AND custom_field_4__c IN :customField4s];
```

Note that this query is strictly a little too broad - it'll bring back all of the Regions which match any combination of field3 and field4, even if no single Account has that exact combination. But that's how we can reduce this to a single bulkified query.

The next step is to iterate back over your Accounts, locate the right Region from `regions` for that Account, and populate its values. Since this is a `before insert` trigger, no DML is required to persist those field updates.

How you'll store and identify the right Region depends a bit on what the content of those fields looks like. One way to do it would be to store the Regions in a `Map<String, Map<String, Region__c>>`, using `custom_field_3__c` and `custom_field_4__c` as the keys for nested Maps. This would be the way to go if the fields have different types, or have free-form content that could potentially contain any delimiter string we might use to concatenate them into a single key (see below).

However, if the content of these fields is amenable to being concatenated with some delimiter, like "custom_field_3__c_value;custom_field_4__c_value", you could store them in a simple `Map<String, Region__c>`, using the concatenated field values as a key to make it easy to locate the matching Region for each Account with one `get()` call.

Comment: Thanks @David-Reed for getting me started. I ended up having to do 4 (!) different for loops to progressively build the data - partly because I also found out that traversing relationships with dot notation in a before trigger does not work, and I had two of those. I used two lists to populate and then query the region data and two maps for data population and retrieval. Whew.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the limitation on relationship traversal - are `custom_field_N__c` and friends actually on a different object related to Account?

Answer (score 0):

At least you can query on Region object outside of all for loops and then just run the list if region data in Account for loop and then compare and prepare a list of applicable records to update outside of for loops.